# What is Modification Type of the sub-tree created as a result of merge of the parent

Tags: opendaylight

The question is about behavior of WriteTransaction.merge. We have Yang  container.

```
container tenants {
    list tenant {
        key tenant-id;
        uses tenant-attributes;
        list logical-network {
            key ln-id;
            uses logical-network-attributes;
        }
    }
}
```

We update this container using

```
InstanceIdentifier<Tenant> path = InstanceIdentifier.builder(Tenants.class)
  .child(Tenant.class, new TenantKey(tenant_id)).build();
writeTransaction.merge(LogicalDatastoreType.CONFIGURATION, path, tenant, true);
```

To update the container we use “**merge**”.

We also have DataTreeChangeListener where we receive information about updates.

```
public void onDataTreeChanged(
    Collection<DataTreeModification<LogicalNetwork>> changed)
```

Notice that we listen not for the container modifications but for subtree of it.

Which ModificationType should we expect  for LogicalNetwork if the Tenant object and LogicalNetwork are new? Should it be SUBTREE_MODIFIED or WRITE?

We use Nitrogen-SR3 and we can see that it is “WRITE”. However, our developers assured me that in the previous version of ODL it was “SUBTREE_MODIFIED”. So, the question is what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the portion of the data tree that you've registered for is rooted at LogicalNetwork, then, when a LogicalNetwork node is created or replaced entirely, the ModificationType will be WRITE. If any child node of an existing LogicalNetwork node is added or updated then it will be SUBTREE_MODIFIED.